# How to insert a decimal point before the last 2 digits of a number?

Tags: php

I have a number, `123457` for example.
I want this: `1234.57`

I have tried with `format_number`, `round()` etc, but it's not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: Am I the only one wondering that PHP doesn't have a division operator?

Comment: `$number / 100` doesn't work?

Comment: And there was an answer (now deleted, of course) that gave an example using `substr`.  Even posted a [working demo](http://codepad.org/sMp5h3i6)!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to make sure you don't get weird results from a bare division like `$number / 100`, you could use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) to format it:

```php
    $formatted_number = sprintf('%.2f', $number / 100);
```

If you wish to output the value immediately, as opposed to saving the string representation in a variable, you can use `printf()` instead.

Comment: I **love** `sprintf()`.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Comment: @mickmackusa that's fair .. i've updated my answer to make it a variable assignment instead.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to divide the number by 100:

```
$num = 123457;
$dec = $num / 100;

echo $dec; // 1234.57
```

Here's [a demo](http://codepad.org/23kMK88f).

Comment: Aha! We liked your `substr` [demo](http://codepad.org/sMp5h3i6) better.

Comment: @devnull A momentary lack of a brain! `:$`